# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Hermanos of: com

Tags: hibernate

Does anybody know why am I getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Hermanos of: com.sahe.model.SalidasProcesionales [FROM com.sahe.model.SalidasProcesionales u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.Hermanos LEFT JOIN FETCH u.PTipoTramo LEFT JOIN FETCH u.Insignias]
```

When I call this method:

```
@Override
public List<SalidasProcesionales> findAll() {
    List<SalidasProcesionales> listadoSalidasProcesionales = null;
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    String hql = "FROM SalidasProcesionales u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.Hermanos LEFT JOIN FETCH u.PTipoTramo LEFT JOIN FETCH u.Insignias";
    try {
        sesion.getTransaction().begin();
        listadoSalidasProcesionales = sesion.createQuery(hql).list();
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        sesion.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listadoSalidasProcesionales;
}
```

by

```
this.salidasProcesionales = new ArrayList<SalidasProcesionales>();
```

Thanks.

The Entity is:

> @Entity
>       @Table(name = "salidas_procesionales", catalog = "sahe")
>       public class SalidasProcesionales implements java.io.Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Integer codigo;
private Insignias insignias;
private Hermanos hermanos;
private PTipoTramo PTipoTramo;
private int anyo;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "codigo", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getCodigo() {
    return this.codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "insignia", nullable = false)
public Insignias getInsignias() {
    return this.insignias;
}

public void setInsignias(Insignias insignias) {
    this.insignias = insignias;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "codigoHermano", nullable = false)
public Hermanos getHermanos() {
    return this.hermanos;
}

public void setHermanos(Hermanos hermanos) {
    this.hermanos = hermanos;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "tipoTramo", nullable = false)
public PTipoTramo getPTipoTramo() {
    return this.PTipoTramo;
}

public void setPTipoTramo(PTipoTramo PTipoTramo) {
    this.PTipoTramo = PTipoTramo;
}

@Column(name = "anyo", nullable = false)
public int getAnyo() {
    return this.anyo;
}

public void setAnyo(int anyo) {
    this.anyo = anyo;
}
}
```

I have deleted constructors for length.

Comment: Please add your `SalidasProcesionales` Entity, and change `Hermanos` for `hermanos`.

Comment: Hey! You were right! Maybe hours of programming don't let you see this small details... Thanks!!! If you create an answer I could give you a positive response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing a join in `JPQL` or `HQL`, you need to use attributes, not entitites, so you need:

```
"FROM SalidasProcesionales u" + 
" LEFT JOIN FETCH u.hermanos" +   // because the property is Hermanos hermanos;
" LEFT JOIN FETCH u.PTipoTramo" + // because the property is PTipoTramo PTipoTramo;
" LEFT JOIN FETCH u.insignias";   // because the property is Insignias insignias;
```

Also you don't need a transaction if you are using only *select* queries.